# cannot use SQLite3 with c++ Native code in Android application

Tags: java, android, c++, sqlite, android-ndk

i want to use SQLite3 in my android application.

but i have a problem , i use CmakeList for native codes management , i added sqlite3 library to my project and also added to CmakeList , but when run application , compiler say 'undefined reference to sqlite3_open' , i do not know where the problem is, whether I did not add the library properly to the program or something , help me please.

my CmakeList.txt

[image]

my java native method

```
native long opendb(String fileName, String tempDir) throws SQLiteException;
```

my native c++ file

[image]

compiler error

[image]

Comment: Did you link -lsqlite3?

Comment: @grizzly i tried this but does not work

Comment: Does your compiler know your libraries' path?

Comment: @grizzly I don't know , how can check it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to extern only splite3.h instead code.

```
extern "C" {

#include "SQLite/sqlite3.h"

}
```

Comment: does not work , again i get error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_open' on compiling